# 'flask instance' does not have attribute 'record' error

Tags: python, api, flask

I have a project where I am trying to build an api using flask and python with the following structure:

```
graph:
    -app.py
    -server.py
    -apis:
        -__init__.py
        -users.py
        -transaction_functions.py
        -neo4j_ops.py
```

In the `server.py` file I am trying to add authentification to the endpoints of my api which are coded in the `users.py` file. My `server.py` file looks like this:

```
import json
from six.moves.urllib.request import urlopen
from functools import wraps

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, _request_ctx_stack
from flask_cors import cross_origin
from jose import jwt



AUTH0_DOMAIN = 'mydomain.eu'
API_AUDIENCE = 'https://my_audience.com'
ALGORITHMS = ["RS256"]


APP = Flask(__name__)

# Error handler
class AuthError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, error, status_code):
        self.error = error
        self.status_code = status_code

@APP.errorhandler(AuthError)
def handle_auth_error(ex):
    #some code


# Format error response and append status code
def get_token_auth_header():
    """Obtains the Access Token from the Authorization Header
    """
    # some code
    return token

def requires_auth(f):
    """Determines if the Access Token is valid
    """
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        #some code
    return decorated


def requires_scope(required_scope):
    """Determines if the required scope is present in the Access Token
    Args:
        required_scope (str): The scope required to access the resource
    """
    #some code
```

And I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask_restplus\api.py", line 183, in init_app
    app.record(self._deferred_blueprint_init)
AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'record'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 16, in <module>
    api.init_app(app)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask_restplus\api.py", line 186, in init_app
    self._init_app(app)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask_restplus\api.py", line 204, in _init_app
    self._register_view(app, resource, *urls, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask_restplus\api.py", line 282, in _register_view
    resource_func = self.output(resource.as_view(endpoint, self, *resource_class_args,
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'
```

As you can see the result of this printstack is not really useful at all since none of these calls comes from any of my files.
The only file involved in that is app.py and it looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Api
from apis import api
import config
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

api.init_app(app)#traceback comes from here.
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

The `apis/__init__.py` file looks like this:

```
from flask_restplus import Api, fields
from .users import api as users
from flask import Flask



api = Api(
    title='Graph Api',
    version='0.2',
)

api.add_namespace(users)
```

Any idea of what the issue is?
If I import app (the flask instance) from `app.py` into `server.py` and use that flask instance created in app rather than creating a new whole flask instance in `server.py` somehow the error goes away, but the issue is that I would then create a circular call of dependencies, so I cant do that.

Comment: Can you add your `apis` code? Also, is your api endpoint a class or function?

Comment: apis is a folder, and in the code I showed you apis refers to the __init__.py file in apis. Anyway apis/__init__.py looks like this:
`
from flask_restplus import Api, fields
from .users import api as users
from flask import Flask



api = Api(
    title='Graph Api',
    version='0.2',
)

api.add_namespace(users)
`
endpoints are classes since I am using Swagger. However they are coded in the `users.py` file.

Comment: Don't name your file app

Comment: It did not work

Answer (score 0):

You already have an app

```
APP = Flask(__name__)
```

And your error handler at least is using that

Yet, you defined a second one

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

And `__name__` here is `app` (the name of the file), which is probably what's breaking things and why the server file isn't broken

Comment: The thing is that is in `server.py` i try to use the app instance defined in `app.py` importing it, I would get a circular dependency that i cannot break. Any suggestion on that?

Comment: Never mind I found a way of doing that and basically have only one flask instance declared in an helper file and importing it both into `server.py` and into `app.py`. I am still getting the same error though.

Comment: I typically put my app in the init file

Comment: Please edit your question to include the updated code

Answer (score -1):

The problem stopped existing as soon as I went back to the version of the code of before adding the `server.py` file, and then I added it again. I have no clue of what the issue was though as the code is actually the same.